# Is there a name for the dimmed background behind a modal dialog?

Tags: css, user-interface, modal-dialog

I'm a little fuzzy on the proper terms related to modal dialogs. There's the box itself that contains the content you read or interact with this (I believe this would be called the modal "dialog"...can it also be called the modal "overlay"?). And then there's the dimmed background behind this box - is there a specific name for the dimmed background (is that the "overlay")?

Comment: If stackoverflow is not the proper place to ask this question, please let me know.

Comment: I thought it was called an overlay.  http://raventools.com/blog/create-a-modal-dialog-using-css-and-javascript/

Comment: @karthikr - opacity is the CSS property used to get the dimmed semi-transparent effect. I'm asking if there's a term used to refer to the dimmed background div.

Comment: Try asking on http://ux.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery UI calls the dimmed background the *overlay*. It has the CSS class `ui-widget-overlay`.

Comment: Well that was originally what I thought, but recently several coworkers seemed to be mixing terms, so I started second-guessing myself. Dictionary.com defines "overlay" as: "to cover, overspread..." and "to finish with a layer", which much more describes the dimmed background than the dialog box with content. On top of that, if jQuery UI is naming the dimmed background 'ui-widget-overlay', then I think overlay is the correct term.

Comment: There's probably not an industry standard for this. It's not something that needs to be referred to very much.

Comment: I've also heard it called a "mask".

Comment: @jbyrd In UIs, "masking" often refers to input fields that display the constant parts, like the parentheses and hyphens in phone numbers. So they may have chosen to avoid that term here.

Comment: ah yes, true, good point.